# collectd folder /etc/collectd/collectd.conf not found in centos 7.2

Tags: centos7, collectd

In CentOS 7.2 using yum I installed collectd (collectd.x86_64 0:5.5.2-1.el7)
I followed the instruction in the below 
http://www.tecmint.com/install-collectd-and-collectd-web-to-monitor-server-resources-in-linux/

It looks like it did not create /etc/collectd/collectd.conf folder. has there been a change in centos 7.2 or the collectd package? a third party tool is looking for this folder during installation.

Comment: In general questions/problems regarding the usability of or inaccuracies in HOWTO's and manuals should be addressed to their author and not posted on ServerFault. - Alternatively read our  [guide to writing good questions](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3609/37681) and post an [on-topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) question that contains sufficient details/errors/configuration-settings about **your setup** to provide you with a good solution, rather than confusing the issue with potential issues in both that guide and/or how accurately it was followed.

Answer (score 0):

You can check paths/files belonging to a RPM package by inspecting it:

```
rpm -ql <package-name>
```

will list all files and directories, the additional `-c` flag will restrict the output to configuration files only.

In rare occasions files and directories are not included as such in the RPM package but created by installation scripts also included in the RPM. You can inspect those scripts with the `--scripts` option:

```
rpm -q --scripts <package-name>
```

If there have been changes in a package the maintainer may have included a description of those changes in the change log:

```
rpm -q --changelog <package-name>
```